# Looping objects in javascript, why does it not matter what "key" is called?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I thought I had to use the word `key` but I don't. Is there a specific reason for this or is this just the default behavior, i.e. loop the keys unless otherwise specified?

```
var theObject = {
    name: "Johnston",
    habits: [ "Coding", "Gaming" ],
    favColor: "blue"
}
```

I can say 'key':

```
for (var key in theObject) {
    console.log(key);
}
```

Or 'anyNameAtAll'

```
for (var anyNameAtAll in theObject) {
    console.log(anyNameAtAll);
}
```

Comment: For variables that you declare (that aren't built-in objects or reserved keywords), you can name whatever you want

Comment: Otherwise `key` is required?

Comment: No, `key` here does not refer to a built-in object or keyword, so the use of the variable name `key` is completely arbitrary, you may name it whatever you want

Comment: Hmm, so maybe it's more like naming a counter `i`, but it could be anything. And by default it loops the keys.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: Yeah, it just hit me that I'm using a variable. I guess my surprise is more that it knows to loop all keys by simply using a for loop and really nothing else.

Comment: @wazz well, that's the magic of `for...in` - its ability to loop properties in an object

Comment: Yup, it's the `in` that didn't click. I'm `in` an object and the keys/props are really all that's there, so loop 'em! Kind of duh, but that was not clicking.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of the for..in loop is

```
 for (variable in object) {
   //statements
 }
```

The "variable" in above syntax can be anything you wish, Eg: "var key" or "var property". On each iteration a different property name in the object is assigned to the variable you declared. So "key" does not hold any special significance over other variable names.

Comment: Thanks I think I just answered my own question via the comments.

Comment: It might be better to use `for (identifier in object)`. ;-)

Comment: Note that if you don't use `var`, `let` or `const` to *declare* the identifier, it will *leak* to the global scope: `(function () { for (variable in {'a': 1}) {} })(); console.log('variable' in window);`